# Debugging Javascript code that duplicate larger image in gallery.

Tags: javascript

I took a break from coding due to moving, and was recently trying to update my website with some new pictures. I have attached a fiddle which shows the problem I am running into. If I want to add a new image (in this case hike1 on fiddle) to my gallery, whenever you click the image to view the larger jpg, it does not display properly. When the thumbnail jpgs are clicked, they displays the image before it, rather than a larger image of that thumbnail. (Clicking the sunset photo displays the hike1 photo, the firespinner photo displays the sunset photo etc..)

Could someone please help? I am sure its a simple fix that I am over looking. It works fine with the images I have, but when I add new ones this happens.

```
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/crookymnster/wk0jrz9s/

Answer (score 1):

```
currentSlide(1)
```

That's the problem right there. If you pass the correct index to that function, you will be able to see the larger image upon clicking the thumbnail. Looking at your fiddle. Here is the updated fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/ywpzh8v2/

Comment: While this is true, it would help if you could detail a little more why that line is the issue. In this case, the problem is that he is using the correct index already in the currentSlide(x) function on each image but then removing one index on the slides[] array. Also, the first image and second have the same index (1)

Comment: Thanks guys I realized it was a minor mistake in my html not my javascript.. simple overlook lol